# Secure authentication and requests with C# through a PHP REST api

Tags: c#, php, security, authentication, encryption

### Introduction

Okay so I've got a website (PHP) with a database (MySQL). You can create an account on this website and edit your details and so on (let's say date of birth, real name, address, and so on).

Now, what I wanna do is to create a desktop application (most likely c# with WPF) that interacts with a REST api (in PHP) from the website, which will allow to :

- Create accounts directly from the application
- Log in to your account
- Be able to edit your details directly from the application

As of now I only want to do a desktop application, but it might evolve into a mobile app. I don't think that is relevant though.

### Creating accounts and logging in

I'm struggling with the create account / log in part. I want it to be as secure as possible. On the website, I'm using password_hash(PASSWORD_BCRYPT) with a cost of 10 to store passwords in the database, and password-verify to check log ins.

Regarding the application, I imagine the way to go is to pass the username and password to the REST api and do the encryption directly on the server side. But sending the password itself sounds terrible so I thought about encrypting it with a secret key that only the application and the website know, so the website can figure out the password and encode it correctly in the database.

If I'm right, what encryption algorithm should I use? If not, how should I do that?

### Edit your details directly from the application

I'm thinking about doing the following : Let's say the user has logged in through the application. If the authentication is successful, the server randomly generates a token (I'll probably use [ircmaxell's Random-Lib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/RandomLib)) and send it as a reply to the application. From then onward, when the application wants to make a request to the api, it adds the username to the datas string, and generates a hash (sha256 for example) with the data string plus the token; then the server can repeat the exact process using the token stored in database to make sure the user actually has the right to access/modify his details, and nobody is trying to pretend to be an user he isn't.

I feel like the problem is, if someone listens to the first api reply after the authentication, he gets the token and can use it to act as if he was the user. Would encrypting it with the same process used for the password be enough to make sure this can't happen?

Last but not least, if I want the user to be able to be directly logged in the next time he starts the application, I guess I have to give the token a permanent durability and store it in a file or something on the computer. But that doesn't sound really safe because anyone could just read the file content and figure out the token.

### Final questions

So. What do you think ? Does it sound good or am I completely off the tracks?

The website hosting is in http://* so I guess using HTTPS communications is not an option here. I know that's a big problem to create something really secured, but I'd still like to make something as safe as possible with what I have.

Thanks a lot for your advices. :)

Btw I tried to make this as clear as possible, hope it worked. I have close to pretty little knowledge of security, encryption, ... so you'll have to speak like to a 3 years old to me.

Comment: I'd like to know more about why HTTPS is not an option? If your hosting provider is unable to give you HTTPS, it really does speak negatively to their suitability for the job.

Comment: You should never reinvent your own authentication, password management or encryption. Use well known libraries and patterns

Answer (score 3):

I think the first, most important piece of advice I could give is to *never* try to roll your own security code, unless you are an absolute expert. You'll want to put together a solution based on the frameworks that .net provides for you.

First things first - your REST API. I'd suggest building on top of ASP.NET Web API. HTTPS is mandatory here - if your hosting provider can't give it to you, you need a new hosting provider. It also conveniently takes care of encryption for you.

There are various security options available for ASP, I'd read this for a detailed overview: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/. Using the existing ASP options will also take care of your requirements around user account creation and self-service.

Comment: Actually my website is using PHP and I'll most likely make my API with PHP. But thanks for the link tho, I'll give it a look. :)

Comment: Ah true. You might want to specify in the question then.

Comment: You're right. :) I'll try to search for libraries to cover the communication part both client and server side, and figure out how I should handle that password issue.

Comment: I'd be shocked if PHP doesn't have its own libraries and patterns to help take care of password management for you - I just wouldn't have the foggiest about them, as my focus is .net :)